# Correlation of nonstationary time series (levels vs differences)

Tags: time-series, correlation, data-transformation, stationarity

I wonder what the relationship between the empirical sample correlation of two time series in levels and the one of the differenced series is.

I know that for nonstationary variables, it makes little sense to calculate the correlation between them, so one should difference the series to make them stationary and calucate the correlation of the differenced series.

**My questions:**

How are the "valid" correlation (between 2 differenced stationary series) and the "wrong" correlation (between 2 series in levels) related?

If the "wrong" correlation strengthens over time, does that mean that the "valid" correlation does too, always?

While intuitively, this might make sense (the two variables are coming "closer together"), it confuses me that the correlation between *stationary* variables should be state-dependent.

Comment: When you talk about correlation changing over time, do you mean the data generating process is changing? (I removed the [tag:differences] tag as its definition is unclear. I added [tag:data-transformation] instead.) Note that for integrated processes, theoretical correlation is ill-defined because variance is infinite, even though sample correlation can always be calculated (but it would not be a sensible estimate of the theoretical correlation just because the estimand is ill-defined).

Comment: Yes! (as far as I understand your question). Basically, the input data change, e.g. corr(Xt,Yt) -> corr(Xt - Xt-1, Yt - Yt-1)

Comment: So you mean that the pair of random variables $(X_t,Y_t)$ have a different correlation than the pair $(X_{t+1},Y_{t+1})$? I am talking about random variables, not their realization which I would denote $(x_t,y_t)$ and $(x_{t+1},y_{t+1})$, respectively. Or are you talking about realizations and thus empirical correlations that for some reason happen to be higher in some windows within your sample and lower in other windows? (I have to go now, will be back only tomorrow.)

Comment: I meant empirical correlation, yes! I am sorry, I did not clarify that. I understand that sample correlation is meaningless for two series that are characterized by unit roots. Yet, in empirical research, there are plenty of studies where researchers draw conclusions from calculating the correlation between two integrated series. Hence, I wondered how the sample correlation of differenced, i.e. stationary series is related to the sample correlation of non-stationary series (the one that I see as "wrong") and whether implications from the one carry over to the other.

Comment: But where does the part of correlation changing over time come? Or should we forget this over time thing and just focus on finding a relationship between correlation between $(x_t,y_t)$ and $(\Delta x_t,\Delta y_t)$?

Comment: You are right, the focus of my question lays on the relationship between the correlation of $(x_t,y_t)$ and the correlation of $(Δx_t,Δy_t)$ (I included the "over time"-part because I was curious what one can and cannot say about the correlation of $(Δx_t,Δy_t)$ when calculating the correlation of $(x_t,y_t)$ for multiple time periods, i.e. how those two measures are related).

Comment: I still don't get the *over time* part. Do you have a rolling window in mind? Or an expanding window? Or yet something else?

Comment: Let me put it that way: One period of time can be subdivided into three distinct time periods. If you go ahead and calculate the correlation of $(x_t,y_t)$, you will get three different results (one for each period). Now, if you observe a pattern (let's say the correlation is weak in period 1, more pronounced in period 2, and even stronger in period 3), I wondered whether you can then say anything about the correlation of $(Δx_t,Δy_t)$ as well. I am interested in how those two measures are related. I should have stated that more precisely, I'm sorry if I am causing confusion here.

Comment: The direction of the correlation between the differenced nonstationary series (and therefore became stationarized series) is not necessarily the same as the direction of the correlation between the levels of the nonstationary series. By direction, I mean "positively directed" (one increases, the other increases; one decreases, the other decreases), and "negatively directed" (inversely propertional).